# can not scroll with image on Andorid horizontal list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-fragments

Hi I am using the horizontal list view in this library 
https://github.com/MeetMe

and I used the adapter which contains imagebutton and textview 
but when I scroll from the image it won't scroll
and I don't know why

can you help me?

main.xml

```
<com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
android:id="@+id/hlvCustomListFriends"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="200dp" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/shared_friends"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
```

adapter.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton_aaa"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_editbar_profile" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_aaa"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton_aaa"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="dd"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I guess, you did't use scrollview in your main.xml

Comment: can you please post your activity class code right now not enough code to solve your problem ?

Comment: Check it There. Posted a Solution for your problem over discussion

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!REAnkAwb!NH9JYrVJkthJAFdMsTGQHYOGmLYCW-RLAUPX1b2PFBY
because the author didn't post a eclipse used file, Umer made the file and I upload it to my MEGA space, hope every can use this if you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using the same library which you are using and got same issues like you are and it is also mentioned in the limitations of the library which you are using so it would be better to move on to another i posted a link that would work like charm.

Use this Horizontal Listview i am using this one and it has proper implementation even the scrol listners can be implemented works like a charms for me.

https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

for eclipse

https://mega.co.nz/#!REAnkAwb!NH9JYrVJkthJAFdMsTGQHYOGmLYCW-RLAUPX1b2PFBY
because the author didn't post a eclipse used file, Umer made the file and I upload it to Disonash(Devon)MEGA space, hope every can use this if you need it.

Comment: how to use it, it only contains gradle build. But I don't know how to use it in eclipse. Is there any tutorial?

Comment: Just Download as Zip, Extract and Import it as Android Project thats it

Comment: Still if you face any issue let me know

Comment: The import android.view.ActionMode cannot be resolved

Comment: Give me a Minute let me make it ready for you then will send it to you

Comment: https://mega.co.nz/#!REAnkAwb!NH9JYrVJkthJAFdMsTGQHYOGmLYCW-RLAUPX1b2PFBY
because the author didn't post a eclipse used file, Umer made the file and I upload it to my MEGA space, hope every can use this if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your main.xml by below one :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <com.meetme.android.horizontallistview.HorizontalListView
 android:id="@+id/hlvCustomListFriends"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="200dp" 
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
 android:layout_below="@+id/shared_friends"
 android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you delete the imageButton you can use the scroll ?...

if you have a custom listView and need use the click of the ImageButton, you need use android:clickable="false"  in your List  ,

Comment: I did, if I set no click listener and it can be scrolled ,but if I set the imagebutton to a onClickListener and it's not workable.

Comment: is because the list is focused when is is pressed, set the atributte  android:clickable="false" in yout list.